# Display an image in an Image control using FileUpload

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I want show an image in an `Image` control as a user select an image file through the `FileUpload` control, but I don't want the image saved on my server.

Answer (score 1):

The best you could do would be to have it uploaded into memory, and without saving it display it using an .ashx or something.

EDIT

Before HTML5, you perhaps could have done it by having a javascript function that takes the directory of the uploaded file and then sets the IMG src property to that filepath.  The image would then load a preview from their own hard drive.  In HTML5 compliant browsers, that filepath is hidden so you can't use it in JavaScript.  This happens in IE8, Chrome, Etc.

Here's another messy way to do it.

First, create a javascript function that will handle the FileUpload controls onchange event.  When this event fires, it will post back the entire form.

```
        function uploadFile() {
        var value = $("#<%=fuTest.ClientID %>").val();
        if (value != '') {
            $("#form1").submit();
        }
    }
```

Here is the upload control:

```
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuTest" onchange="uploadFile()" />
```

Now, when someone chooses a file, the form posts back and you can then take the image into memory on the server and display it when the postback is complete.

Comment: it is well, but how to send byte array (image file) to generic handler file (.ashx)?

Comment: store the image in the cache object, or the session, and then pass a key to access it to the ashx handler.  it can then stream out the image if you set the content type correctly.  this won't really work if you want to show an immediate preview, it will just show the image to the user right after they've successfully uploaded it without storing it on your server.

Comment: i edited my response with some new info.  there isn't any clean way to do this that i'm aware of, especially since browsers aren't allowing javascript access to the files.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done - to show the "preview" you have to have the image stored somewhere on your server at least temporarily so you can generate and render the `<img>` tag on your page.

Comment: @hamed - What you want to do cannot be done. Both dahmsbrak's and my solutions are at least approximations of what you want to do, and about as much as is possible.

Comment: i want when user selected an image with FileUpload control from, image has been automatically preview in an image control.

Comment: @hamed - I know what you want. What you want **IS NOT POSSIBLE** (as I have now stated three times). The best you can do is one of the things that we have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you'll need to use a custom imageControl that has an assignable Bitmap property. Here's an article that describes one:

[Egghead Cafe Article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/asp-net/e1a14e2c-e746-4bed-a552-24c632bd2709/aspnet-inmemory-image-control-with-builtin-resizing-of-posted-file.aspx)